# Node.js: sendfile for unknown file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

Using a MEAN environment, I am returning images to the client upon request. Example:

```
res.sendfile("./pathtoimage/someImage.jpg");
```

My problem: the path to the image (as well as the image name) is calculated at runtime, following a specific scheme so I know the path and actual name of the image. What I don't know is the file type of the image, hence missing the file extension (such as .jpg, .gif, .png). Instead of checking, if the file exists in either one version, can I instead write something like this:

```
res.sendfile("./pathtoimage/someImage.*");
```

Return that file with whatever extension you may find, instead of manually checking if a certain version of that file exists? Any other suggestions? Otherwise I'd go and sequentially try to access all variations until I find the right combination and return that. I was just wondering if there was a quicker and more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are alone with `fs.exists`.

If you consider using a reverse proxy like `nginx` to serve static files, you will have more options to serve image files with several possible extensions.

`nginx` has `try_files` directive that can be used for this purpose:

```
try_files $uri.jpg $uri.gif $uri.png $uri/ =404
```

Comment: Hm ok. I think I might just use a Promise collection like any() to check all variations concurrently and then go for the existent file. Thanks!